# Is it possible to get all the pull requests made by a user on different repos using some API?

Tags: github, github-api, pull-request

I am making an application where I need to get all the pull requests made by a particular user on various repositories.

I can get all the pull request on a particular repository but found no suitable API to get all the pull request by a user.

What kind of API call can I make to get those PR filtered by author?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [List Pull Request API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests) has a head filter:

`head   string`

> Filter pulls by head **user** and branch name in the format of `user:ref-name`.

Example: `github:new-script-format`.

That wouldn't work in your case, as you don't know the branch names, only the author.

Use instead the [search API for issues](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues)

```
GET /search/issues
```

It can filter by:

- **[`type`](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues#search-issues-or-pull-requests)**: With this qualifier you can restrict the search to issues (issue) or **pull request (`pr`)** only.
- **[`author`](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues#search-by-the-author-of-an-issue-or-pull-request)**: Finds issues or pull requests created by a certain user.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code

```
var d=2018-09-30T10%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00   //start date
var f=2018-11-01T12%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00   //end date
var t=iamshouvikmitra                     //username


$.getJSON("https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=-label:invalid+created:" + d + ".." + f + "+type:pr+is:public+author:" + t + "&per_page=300", function(e) {


}
```

Infact this is similar to the code that `https://hacktoberfest.digitalocean.com` Uses to count the number of pull request you have submitted during the month of october.